# How do I check my MySQL table to make sure that I don't enter the same thing twice?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Right now I'm trying to create a PHP/MySQL setup that adds a name to a database. I don't want it to add the name to the database if it already exists though. Right now it is adding the name to the database regardless.

I have three files that I use for this.

First is the Names.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>About</h1>

        <form action="Insert.php" method="post">
            <p>What is your full name?</p><input type="text" name="names"><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Next is the Insert.php file:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","a7068104_user2","wiseguy1345");
if(!$con) {
    die("could not connect to localhost:" .mysql_error());
} 

mysql_select_db("a7068104_world") or die("Cannot connect to database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names_1 ORDER BY names");
if(!$result) {
    die('Invalid SELECT query:' .mysql_error());
}

$sql="INSERT INTO names_1 (names) VALUES ('$_POST[names]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("refresh:1.5; url=NamesAction.php");

mysql_close($con)
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <p>You will be redirected back to the <b>Names</b> page in a moment.</p>
        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And lastly there is the NamesAction.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
    <h1>Names</h1>

    <?php 
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","a7068104_user2","wiseguy1345");
        if(!$con) {
            die("could not connect to localhost:" .mysql_error());
        } 

        mysql_select_db("a7068104_world") or die("Cannot connect to database");
    ?>

    <?php
        mysql_query("LOCK TABLES names_1 WRITE;");

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names_1 ORDER BY names DESC LIMIT 100000");
        if(!$result) {
            die('Invalid SELECT query:' .mysql_error());
        }

        echo "<table border='2'>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['names'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

        mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");

        mysql_close($con);
    ?>

    <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help as I have no idea how to make sure that I don't enter something into the database twice! What I want to do is check the database to make sure it isn't added already, if it is added already send a message to the user and do add it, and if it isn't added already send a message saying it is adding to the database and add it to the database.

Thanks,
leonardude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't use `mysql_*` series of functions. But I'm gonna write the following code using them since you are probably more used to them. But seriously, don't use them. Instead use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

```
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['names']);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM names_1 WHERE names='$name'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
       //Already in Db
 }
 else{
      $query = "INSERT INTO names_1 (names) VALUES('$name')";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if($result){
          //successful
      }
      else{
          //Unsuccessful
      }
 }
```

Or just let the database engine handle the task for you by adding a unique constraint to the columns that are to be unique as other answers suggested.

Comment: It says that the mysql_num_row function is undefined so the code doesn't work. And for now I have to use the mysql_* series of functions because this is for a class. I do know that the mysqli_* functions are better.

Comment: my bad . its `mysql_num_rows`. updating

Answer (score 1):

Use the UNIQUE key.

```
CREATE TABLE someTable(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_unique_value INT UNIQUE
);
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create unique key for fields you need to be unique in database and try/catch thrown exception when duplicate data is entered.

Answer (score 0):

This check may be done on the database side

```
ALTER TABLE `names_1`.`names` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`names`);
```